# MySQL Select where Tag = "First tag" AND Tag = "Another tag" using reference table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database structure:

[image: Text]

The table peekable_tag is essentially a dictionary of lots of different tags.

The table peekable_url is a table full of different URLs and then each URL can be referenced to multiple tags.

For example, a url such as carmechanic.com can have both the tags "Car" and "Mechanic" assigned to it. 
And a url such as teslacardirectory.com could have three tags, "Car", "Tesla" and "Mechanic" assigned to it.

using the following query i can pull all of the urls up that have 1 keyword assigned, for example, the keyword "Car"

```
Select
peekable_tag.tag,
peekable_url.id,
peekable_url.url
From
peekable_tag Inner Join
peekable_urltotag On peekable_urltotag.peekable_tag_id = peekable_tag.id Inner Join
peekable_url On peekable_urltotag.peekable_URL_id = peekable_url.id
Where
peekable_tag.tag = 'Car'
```

Would return both URLs.

However...

How do I alter this so i can narrow the search down with multiple keywords? 
So if i searched for "Car" and "Tesla" as a keyword, only teslacardirectory.com would appear.

I tried

```
peekable_tag.tag = 'Car' AND peekable_tag.tag = 'Tesla'
```

But that doesn't return any results.

I thought about nesting one search query inside another, but then I would be limited to only using two keywords. Or nest three queries, but then id be limited to 3 keywords... Is there a way of achieving what im trying to do without limiting how many keywords can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
Select u.id, u.url
From peekable_tag t Inner Join
     peekable_urltotag ut
     On ut.peekable_tag_id = t.id Inner Join
     peekable_url u
     On ut.peekable_URL_id = u.id
Where t.tag in ('Car', 'Tesla')
group by u.id, u.url
having count(*) = 2;  -- both tags match
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm - So if i was to use 3 tags, i would change having count(*) = 2;to having count(*) = 3;... correct?

Comment: @PaulF . . . Exactly.